# What is my type not inferable in this case?

Tags: swift

I have a protocol:

```
protocol Model {}
```

And structs using this protocol:

```
struct Foo: Model {}
```

Then I have a different protocol with a generic:

```
protocol Controller {
    func fun<T: Model>() -> Observable<T>
}
```

The controller's implementation of the method can infer the type:

```
class Bar: Controller {
    func fun<Foo>() -> Observable<Foo> {
        // return an observable
    }
}
```

What I thought I was doing here was have two 'base' protocols, one for models and one for controllers. The base controller dictates a method to implement using a generic of the base model group, the implementation can then specify which model to use. After writing all that it compiles fine and everything seems in order, but when I make an instance of `Bar` and try to call `fun()` on it I get an error saying `Generic parameter 'Foo' can not be inferred`.
Here's a minimum complete example to reproduce with:

```
protocol Model {}

struct Foo: Model {}

protocol Controller {
    func fun<T: Model>() -> Observable<T>
}

class Bar: Controller {
    func fun<Foo>() -> Observable<Foo> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            let cancel = Disposables.create {
                // clean up
            }

            return cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `Bar().fun()` will now give the error: `Generic parameter 'Foo' can not be inferred`

There are two things I don't understand here. The first is how can it know that I call the implementation that specified Foo while at the same time not being able to infer the type? Foo is not a generic, it's the actual type of the Foo struct. The second thing I don't understand and the actual question here, is **if I call a method on an instance that implemented and specified a generic method, why can it not infer the type**?

Comment: When you call Bar().fun() you just call a method with no arguments. the method belongs to Bar, but there is no Foo struct in sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding is mistaking the `Foo` in this method as the `Foo` struct:

```
func fun<Foo>() -> Observable<Foo> {
    // return an observable
}
```

It's not! `Foo` in the context of the above method is just another generic type parameter!

---

What you are trying to achieve here...

> The base controller dictates a method to implement using a generic of the base model group, the implementation can then specify which model to use.

...should be done with associated types:

```
protocol Model {}

struct Foo: Model {}

protocol Controller {
    associatedtype ModelType: Model
    func fun() -> Observable<ModelType>
}

class Bar: Controller {
    typealias ModelType = Foo
    func fun() -> Observable<Foo> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            let cancel = Disposables.create {
                // clean up
            }

            return cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func fun<Foo>(_ type: Foo.Type) -> Observable<Foo> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            let cancel = Disposables.create {
                // clean up
            }

            return cancel
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it with:

```
Bar.fun(YourModel.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to fix the implementation of the `fun` method:

```swift
class Bar: Controller {
    func fun<T: Model>() -> Observable<T> {
        return Observable<T>.create { observer in

            let cancel = Disposables.create {
                // clean up
            }

            return cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you'll need to infer the generic `Foo` parameter within the caller like:

```swift
let observableFoo: Observable<Foo> = Bar().fun()
```